# Arduino Core: debugging esp8266 with gdbstub causes SIGABRT in gdb

Tags: arduino, gdb, remote-debugging, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to figure out how to debug code on the esp8266 using `gdb` with the `gdbstub` included in Arduino Core, following [these instructions](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gdb.html).

I've loaded a very simple example program onto my esp8266 Amica NodeMCU 1.0 board, and added the required `Serial.begin` and `gdbstub_init` function calls.

```c
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <GDBStub.h>

/*
  ESP8266 Blink by Simon Peter
  Blink the blue LED on the ESP-01 module
  This example code is in the public domain

  The blue LED on the ESP-01 module is connected to GPIO1
  (which is also the TXD pin; so we cannot use Serial.print() at the same time)

  Note that this sketch uses LED_BUILTIN to find the pin with the internal LED
*/

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  gdbstub_init();
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); // Initialize the LED_BUILTIN pin as an output
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,
               LOW); // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
  // but actually the LED is on; this is because
  // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  delay(1000); // Wait for a second
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN,
               HIGH); // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  delay(2000); // Wait for two seconds (to demonstrate the active low LED)
}
```

When I load this code onto the device and start up `xtensa-lx106-elf-gdb` using the setup options as outlined in the instructions, it starts up correctly and I can create breakpoints. However, whenever I try to step over a line of code (e.g., `digitalWrite` on line 24), `gdb` crashes with the error:

```
'xtensa-lx106-elf-gdb' terminated by signal SIGABRT (Abort)
```

I can't figure out what is causing it to crash when I step over function calls (and I've been able to reproduce this with other statements as well). Does anyone know how to fix this?